# How to achieve this kind of sorting query in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, listview, sqflite

IM trying to achieve look from pic below, data coming from local db, using sqflite.

[image]

I have db "model" class, and db class for int, query methods ext..

```
  //call form db, two columns with specific category:

  Future<List<Confession>> getList({String query1, String query2}) async {

    await initDatabase();  

    List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery(
        'SELECT DISTINCT $query1,Classification FROM movies WHERE Category=("$query2") AND id ORDER by Classification'); 
  
    return list.map((confession) => Confession.fromJson(confession)).toList();
  }
```

In my User UI class IM building widget like this:

```
 Widget _summaryItem(String title, {String queryCategory}) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
          border:
              Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(199, 199, 199, 1), width: 1.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(5, 5, 5, 0.2), blurRadius: 5.0)
          ],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ExpansionTile(
            title: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: '$title\n',
                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(165, 91, 83, 1),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: "Category:",
                        style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                            fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                  ]),
            ),
            children: [
              Divider(
                thickness: 2,
              ),
                   FutureBuilder<List<Confession>>(
                      future: dbService.getList(
                          query1: 'OutputSummary', query2: queryCategory),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return _outPut(
                                  snapshot.data[index].outputsummary,
                                  classification:
                                      snapshot.data[index].classification);
                            });
                      })

            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

And I end up something like pic below dont mind titles this is just mock..

[image]

So how to make listing like in first image, do I make query for each classification then join in the list or there is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expandable Widget for list

You will get your answers in this link
[expandable_widget](https://medium.com/viet-flutter-developers/expandable-list-widget-packages-cb5e054e4c58)

Comment: I already use ExpansionTile , Classification "subcategory" dose not have to be expandable, only like header.